# Code to disable magnifier, set wallpaper, and save image in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a web app with custom buttons (images). Google Chrome displays three icons when hovering over them; Magnifier, Set Wallpaper, and Save Image. If you're a Google Chrome user, I'm sure you've seen them. Not only is it ugly and distracting, and pretty useless in this instance, it looks to me like these extra operations are slowing things down. Is there any way that I can disable this operation for my page or for individual images?

Please note that this is a programming question, not one about setting features in Google Chrome. The problem would not be solved by disabling this feature in my copy of Chrome. I'm concerned about having the page work well for all visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a default Chrome feature, but comes with the [Chrome Toolbox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn). If people have the extension installed, it's reasonable to assume they want that functionality.

Unless they've forgotten they've installed it and don't know where the icons are coming from, but even then I'd write that off as "user error".

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Yes, I did exactly that. Had no idea that it was the extension. Now I can disable in my own copy with a clear conscience. I guess it's still a good question ... I've seen other people asking while trying to google for an answer before posting. You gave the first definitive answer as far as I know. I'll accept your answer as soon as the stackoverflow lets me. (You're just too quick.)