# Disabling Image Magnifier

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension that works with images. The problem that I have is that when an image is larger than the screen, Chrome automatically resizes the image to fit the screen and it turns the cursor into a "magnifying glass" that zooms the image in/out when the user clicks on the image.

For my application, this behavior actually stands in the way of what I am trying to do, and I am wondering if anyone knows how to disable this image magnifier (such that the user can click on the image without the image changing size on the screen).

I searched the entire stackoverflow for "chrome image magnifier" but there is only one relevant posting

[Code to disable magnifier, set wallpaper, and save image in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195910/code-to-disable-magnifier-set-wallpaper-and-save-image-in-google-chrome)

which says that the magnifier comes (and can be disabled) in the Chrome ToolBox, which is not even available for download anymore

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn?hl=en

So I believe this image magnifier is now an inherent part of the Chrome browser, but I would still like to disable it in my extension.

Thanks

Comment: You can display a full page div with the image as its background on first load.

Comment: @wOxxOm I needed the user and the software to interact with the image (click on the image, draw on the image) so I ended up keeping the original image on an off-screen canvas but presenting on the screen a scaled-down image (that is smaller than the browser window) to avoid the "magnifying glass issue."
I have not tried using a background image so am not sure what the challenges would be or if that would have been easier in such an application. Thanks.